# Sequelize combination of unique constraint based on value

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have tried to insert data using sequelize. I have the following model

```
const MyModel = sequelize.define(
    'User', {
      userId: {primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
      userName: {type: Sequelize.TEXT, unique: true},
      userKey: {type: Sequelize.TEXT, unique: true},
      enabled: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        set(val) {
          this.setDataValue('enabled', true);
        }
      },
    })
```

I have the following data in the user table

| 1 | Manu | Manu | false |

I am getting the duplicate error message while I am trying to insert the data using the above model ( note that the current entry has the "enabled" field as False ). But the error should return only when the "enable" field is true, otherwise, it should allow me to add a new record.

What I am trying to achieve is the combination check using enabled + userkey and enabled + username

Answer (score 0):

You can define combination of unique in Schema

```
const myModel = sequelize.define("my_table", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        unique: true,
    },
    userEmail: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
   },{
     indexes: [
        {
            unique: true,
            fields: ['role', 'userEmail']
        }
    ]
 });
```